# How can I place a sub-header inside of the side menu?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

We are working on an application, which uses `ngCordova` and would like to implement a side menu. The side menu has been implemented, as shown below.

[image]

After adding the subheader, the menu looks like this:
[image]

---

This is our code for the side menu:

```
<ion-view title="Home" ng-app="app.controllers"  >
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">Subheader</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-side-menus ng-controller="homeCtrl">

        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
                <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
                    </button>
                </ion-nav-buttons>               
            </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content>


        <ion-side-menu side="left" >

            <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable bar-dark">
                <h1 class="title">Category</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>

            <ion-list class="dark">
                <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="" class="item item-icon-left" >
                    <i class="icon ion-ios7-ionic-outline ion-ios-home-outline"></i><span style="color:#666">Home</span>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/tab/home" class="item item-icon-left" >
                    <i class="icon ion-ios7-help ion-ios-home-outline"></i><span style="color:#666">Home</span>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="" class="item item-icon-left" >
                    <i class="icon ion-ios7-help ion-ios-paw-outline"></i><span style="color:#666">Dogs</span>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="" class="item item-icon-left" >
                    <i class="icon ion-ios7-help ion-ios-cog-outline"></i><span style="color:#666">Profile Settings</span>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="" class="item item-icon-left" >
                    <i class="icon ion-ios7-help ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i><span style="color:#666">History Orders</span>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
</ion-view>
```

---

We would like the subheader to move left and right like the menu button, but it is not doing that right now. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the subheader outside of the element for the side menu, which is why it is not acting the way you would like it to. You can solve this by moving the following code:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader bar-positive">
  <h1 class="title">Subheader</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
```

To the`<ion-side-menu side="left>`:

```
<ion-side-menu side="left">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable bar-dark">
    <h1 class="title">Category</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Subheader</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
```